# Find specific word index after a given word in String Java

Tags: java, string

Say I have String

```
String str = "Hello all, the world is going to end here and I am the only end character which is in the end game of the end world";
```

Now I want to write a function where I will pass a whole string, matchingWord, wordToFindAfterMatchingWord

So let's suppose I want to find the index of "game" but that "game" word should be after "end" word and the word "end" can be n number of times in String. I don't want to use Regex as I am thinking of making this function generic.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: do you want to find "game" in "... end game ..." or also in "... end something game ..." ?  Usually you can use one of the `indexOf()` methods of `String` like [`indexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int))

Comment: AFA I understand your requirement, the expected output should be `-1`. Since there is no `game` present after last `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone said, you can use method indexOf(String,int) with a starting index:

```
public static int indexOf(String str, String word, String precededBy) {
    int i = str.indexOf(precededBy);
    if (i < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return str.indexOf(word, i+precededBy.length());
}
```

Now this:

```
System.out.println(indexOf(str, "game", "end"));
```

Will print 94