# Find index of next word after the given word

Tags: java, substring, indexof

I am trying to write a Java function with the following parameters:

- `String str`: the sample text
- `String word`: a word
- `String nextWord`: another word

If I pass a given `str`, a `word`, and `nextWord` parameters, it should return me the index of first occurrence of `nextWord` calculated from the word `word`, if there are any, otherwise it should return `-1`.

Suppose I have the following `String` for the 1st parameter:

```java
String s = "Hatred was spreading everywhere, blood was being spilled everywhere, wars were breaking out everywhere      and dinosaurs are everywhere, but please note I want the first and index.";
```

In the function I will pass `String s` as the value of `str` parameter, `"everywhere"` literal for `word`, and `"and"` liter for `nextWord`, respectively.

If `"and"` is just after `"everyWhere"` as in the above `String`, it returns me the index of `"and"`, otherwise it returns `-1`.

I would like to avoid using Regex.

I tried with the following sample code:

```java
public static int indexOfPreceded(String str, String word, String nextWord) {
    int i = StringUtils.indexOfIgnoreCase(str, nextWord);
    if (i < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    return StringUtils.indexOfIgnoreCase(str, word, i + nextWord.length());
}
```

Executing the code above, with the following `str` parameter (where the word `"and"` is not after `"everywhere"`), `"and"` for `word`, and
`"everywhere"` for `nextWord`:

```java
String s =  "Hatred was spreading everywhere, blood was being spilled everywhere, wars were breaking out everywhere dinosaurs are everywhere, but please note I want the first and index.";
```

Since in the String `s`, there is no `"and"` before `"everywhere"`, I expect `-1` as result, but my function returns `158` as the index.

Comment: it probably would have been better to edit the previous version of your question: [Find specific word index after a given word in String Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77925627/85421) (but you probably will also ignore my comment here :- ( )

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your function to properly check if the nextWord appears just after the word. The approach should be to find the index of the word first, and then check if the nextWord immediately follows it.

```
public static int indexOfPreceded(String str, String word, String nextWord) {
    int currentIndex = 0;
    int wordIndex = -1;
    
    while ((wordIndex = str.indexOf(word, currentIndex)) != -1) {
        int nextWordIndex = wordIndex + word.length();
        int endIndex = nextWordIndex + nextWord.length();

        if (endIndex <= str.length() && str.substring(nextWordIndex, endIndex).equals(nextWord)) {
            return nextWordIndex;
        }

        currentIndex = nextWordIndex;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The code is not working in the case I described, it's not checking the entire string it's just checking the first occurrence of the word "everywhere" and then checking the index of word "and". Please note the word "everywhere" can be multiple times but the word "everywhere" followed by "and" is just once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return the first occurrence of the described scenario a simple `while` loop like the following will to the trick.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var sentence = "Hatred was spreading everywhere, blood was being spilled everywhere, wars were breaking out everywhere      and dinosaurs are everywhere, but please note I want the first and index.";

        // your sample
        var word = "and";
        var nextWord = "everywhere";
        System.out.println(indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(sentence, word, nextWord));

        // other tests
        var words = sentence.split(" ");
        var i = 4;
        System.out.println(indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(sentence, words[i], words[i+1]) == i + 1);
        System.out.println(indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(sentence, words[i-1], words[i]) == i);
        System.out.println(indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(sentence, words[i], words[i]) == -1);
        System.out.println(indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(sentence, words[i+1], words[i]) == -1);
        System.out.println(indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(sentence, words[i], words[i+2]) == -1);
        System.out.println(indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(sentence, words[i], "somearbitrarywordthatdoesnotexistinthesentence") == -1);
        System.out.println(indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(sentence, "somearbitrarywordthatdoesnotexistinthesentence", words[i]) == -1);
    }

    // Assumption: you want to return the first occurrence
    public static int indexOfFirstWordPrecededBy(String sentence, String word, String nextWord){
        var words = sentence.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
            if(words[i].compareToIgnoreCase(word) == 0 && words[i+1].compareToIgnoreCase(nextWord) == 0){
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
-1
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

Please note: This implementation doesn't handle some of the edge cases which you should think of. For example it currently only handles single spaces as word separators, you wanna think about how to handle multiple blanks, `,`, `-` or other punctuation marks typically found in sentences. As an example consider `word = "spreading"` and `nextWord = "everywhere"`: This should probably return `3` but doesn't since the program currently does consider `,` to be part of the word therefore `word = "spreading"` and `nextWord = "everywhere,"` will return `3`.

In terms of performance this is `O(n)` but it creates a lot of strings on the heap which have to be garbage collected so there are more efficient implementations possible, but for most purposes this should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputString = "Hatred was spreading everywhere and, blood was being spilled everywhere, wars were breaking out everywhere and dinosaurs are everywhere, but please note I want the first and index.";
    String wordToFind = "everywhere";
    String nextWord = " and";

    List<Integer> occurrences = findOccurrences(inputString, wordToFind);
    System.out.println("Occurrences of '" + wordToFind + "': " + occurrences);

    if(occurrences.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Word 'and' not found after 'everywhere' in the string or return -1");
        return;
    }

    for (int index : occurrences) {
        int startPoint = index + wordToFind.length();
        String wordAfterEverywhere = inputString.substring(startPoint, startPoint + nextWord.length());

        if (wordAfterEverywhere.equalsIgnoreCase(nextWord)) {
            System.out.println("Word 'and' found after 'everywhere' at index: " + startPoint);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Word 'and' not found after 'everywhere' in the string or return -1");
        }
    }
}

private static List<Integer> findOccurrences(String inputString, String wordToFind) {
    int index = inputString.indexOf(wordToFind);
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (index != -1) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Occurrence " + count + " found at index: " + index);
        indexList.add(index);
        index = inputString.indexOf(wordToFind, index + 1);
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println("No occurrences of the word \"" + wordToFind + "\" found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Total occurrences of the word \"" + wordToFind + "\": " + count);
    }

    return indexList;
}
```

}